# Подскажите как правильно добавить виртуальный деструктор - C++

Tags: c++, двусвязный-список

Доброго времени суток

Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно добавить виртуальный деструктор в класс `Int`, `Double`, `String` и что он должен удалять?

Заранее благодарен.

```
class Type
{
public:
    virtual ~Type() = 0; 
    virtual void ShowData() = 0;
};

class Int : public Type
{
private:
    int i_int;
public:
    Int() : i_int(NULL)
    {}
    Int(int i) : i_int(i)
    {}
    void putData(int valueInt); //ввод данных
    void ShowData(); // вывод данных
};

class Double : public Type
{
private:
    double d_dou;
public:
    Double() : d_dou(0)
    {}
    Double(double d) : d_dou(d)
    {}

    void putData(double valueDouble); //ввод данных
    void ShowData(); // вывод данных
};

class String : public Type
{
private:
    string s_str;
public:
    String() : s_str("")
    {}
    String(string s)  
    {
        s_str = s;
    }
    void putData(string strString); //ввод данных
    void ShowData(); // вывод данных
};

enum Kind { IntValue, DoubleValue, StringValue };

struct Node       //Структура являющаяся звеном списка
{
    Int integer_object; 
    Double double_object;
    String string_object;
    Type * object;
    Kind TypeValue;
    Node *Next,*Prev; //Указатели на адреса следующего и предыдущего элементов списка
};


class List   //Создаем тип данных Список
{
public:
    Node *Head,*Tail; //Указатели на адреса начала списка и его конца

public:
    List():Head(NULL),Tail(NULL){}; //Инициализируем адреса как пустые
    List(const List&);// Конструктор копирования
    List& operator = (const List&);
    ~List()//Деструктор
    {   
        while (Head) //Пока по адресу на начало списка что-то есть
        {
            Tail=Head->Next; //Резервная копия адреса следующего звена списка
            if(Tail)
                Tail->Next = NULL;
            delete Head; //Очистка памяти от первого звена
            Head=Tail; //Смена адреса начала на адрес следующего элемента
        }
    }; 

    void addElementToList(Node * x); //Добавление элемента в список
    void getElementFromListByPossition(int numEllement); // Вывод элемента по номеру
    void getAllElementFromList(Node *pbeg); //Вывод всех элементов списка
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

классы `Int`, `String` и `Double` не содержат ничего такого, что нужно удалять вручную. Поэтому, достаточно определить тело деструктора в базовом классе и все будет ок.

поэтому, допишите такое

```
Type::~Type() {}
```

Comment: Т.е если я правильно понял достаточно прописать 
Type::~Type() {}
и прописывать 
Int::~Int() {};
Double::~Double() {};
Sting::~Sting() {};
нет необходимости? Верно?

Comment: да, в данном случае это так и есть.

Comment: Большое спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Виртуальный деструктор нужен, чтобы происходило правильное удаление дочернего объекта через указатель на базовый.

Например:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base
{
public:
    ~Base()
    {
        std::cout << "Base dtor" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    ~Derived()
    {
        std::cout << "Derived dtor" <<std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{

    Base* base = new Derived();

    delete base;

    std::cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Что тут произойдёт. Вызовется конструктор объекта Base. Потом вызовется конструктор объекта Derived. Потом вызовется **деструктор Base**. Вывод будет следующим:

```
Base dtor
```

В этом случае, как подсказал KoVadim в комментариях, согласно стандарту языка мы получим неопределённое поведение.

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual ~Base()
    {
        std::cout << "Base dtor" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    ~Derived()
    {
        std::cout << "Derived dtor" <<std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{

    Base* base = new Derived();

    delete base;

    std::cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

А здесь уже удаление произойдёт полностью (обратно вызову конструкторов)

```
Derived dtor
Base dtor
```

Comment: **Base разрушился, а Derived остался нетронутым. Если же сделать деструктор Base виртуальным:** не пишите неправду. Согласно 5.3.5.6 стандарта (ревизия N3291) в этом случае UB.

Comment: @KoVadim, да, изначально я написал, что Derived не был разрушен полностью. Но зачем-то исправил

Comment: даже фраза "разрушен частично" неверна. Да, обычно так и происходит, но так как это UB, то компилятор может сделать все что угодно, в том числе и корректно все удалить.

Comment: @KoVadim, учту на будущее